# Printing the functions with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have created an if statement function. And with this way I am supposed to print the largest number of the inputs (Please check my code). However, as there should not be any errors, or mistakes in the code itself, I still can not print out the largest_Number. Could you please help me with that?

I have tried writing the print() statement outside the function, then inside, also typing print(largest_Number) in every if lines, still nothing has been changed.

```
Number_1 = int(input("Please type your 1st number: "))
Number_2 = int(input("Please type your 2nd number: "))
Number_3 = int(input("Please type your 3rd number: "))
Number_4 = int(input("Please type your 4th number: "))
Number_5 = int(input("Please type your 5th number: "))
Number_6 = int(input("Please type your 6th number: "))

def largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6):
    if (Number_1 >= Number_2) and (Number_1 >= Number_3) and (Number_1 >= Number_4) and (Number_1 >= Number_5) and (Number_1 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number == Number_1;
    else:
        if (Number_2 >= Number_1) and (Number_2 >= Number_3) and (Number_2 >= Number_4) and (Number_2 >= Number_5) and (Number_2 >= Number_6):
            largest_Number == Number_2
        else:
            if (Number_3 >= Number_1) and (Number_3 >= Number_2) and (Number_3 >= Number_4) and (Number_3 >= Number_5) and (Number_3 >= Number_6):
                largest_Number == Number_3
            else:
                if (Number_4 >= Number_1) and (Number_4 >= Number_2) and (Number_4 >= Number_3) and (Number_4 >= Number_5) and (Number_4 >= Number_6):
                    largest_Number == Number_4
                else:
                    if (Number_5 >= Number_1) and (Number_5 >= Number_2) and (Number_5 >= Number_3) and (Number_5 >= Number_4) and (Number_5 >= Number_6):
                        largest_Number == Number_5
                    else:
                        if (Number_6 >= Number_1) and (Number_6 >= Number_2) and (Number_6 >= Number_3) and (Number_6 >= Number_4) and (Number_6 >= Number_5):
                            largest_Number == Number_6
                            print(largest_Number)
```

Comment: All of that function can be replaced with `def largest(*args): print(max(args))` btw, and call it with `largest(Number_1, Number_2,...,Number_6)`

Comment: @roganjosh you're right, but OP called it "an if statement function", so it's probably an intentional exercise with if statements.

Comment: Just a hint, in this kind of situation I would use the conditional checks in the opposite way to avoid unnecessary nesting. i.e. check for `False` condition first and return if so. Then you can write the `True` case in the same level of the initial if without using an `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors:

1. Your code has `largest_Number == Number_6` (etc.), but `==` checks for equality. you want `largest_Number = Number_6 (etc.)`
2. your final `print()` is nested inside the last `if` statement. You want to take it out to the outermost level.

Also, the code can be greatly simplified by the use of the `max()` function, but since you called it "an if statement function", I assume that this is on purpose. If not, you can do:

```
Number_1 = int(input("Please type your 1st number: "))
Number_2 = int(input("Please type your 2nd number: "))
Number_3 = int(input("Please type your 3rd number: "))
Number_4 = int(input("Please type your 4th number: "))
Number_5 = int(input("Please type your 5th number: "))
Number_6 = int(input("Please type your 6th number: "))

def largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6):
    largest_number = max([Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6])
    print(largest_number)

largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6)
```

Comment: the thing is it still does not want to print the answer.... :(

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: like what should I do?

Comment: `largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6)`

Comment: Do you know the difference between defining a function and calling it?

Comment: make sure the last line ```largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6) ``` is at the end of your program

Answer (score 0):

That == should be replaced by = ( The Assignment Operator )...

There where the_laregest == variable

Answer (score 0):

Below is more concise code to get largest number from given input numbers (store numbers in a list and shown below):

Input

```
a=[int(x) for x in input("Please type your numbers").split()]
print(a)
```

Output

```
Please type your numbers1 2 3 4 5 6

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To get max of the numbers:

```
max(a)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: I need to code the inputs as I have already done, and continue from that, still thanks for the best solution. But I got an issue about the max() as it does not work in my case (does not print out the greatest)....

Comment: In your case the numbers are discrete and the `max` function works on lists

Comment: Yes, pass a list of values and call `max` function

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow & Hope this helps!

```
def largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6):
    if (Number_1 >= Number_2) and (Number_1 >= Number_3) and (Number_1 >= Number_4) and (Number_1 >= Number_5) and (Number_1 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_1;
    else:
        if (Number_2 >= Number_1) and (Number_2 >= Number_3) and (Number_2 >= Number_4) and (Number_2 >= Number_5) and (Number_2 >= Number_6):
            largest_Number = Number_2
        else:
            if (Number_3 >= Number_1) and (Number_3 >= Number_2) and (Number_3 >= Number_4) and (Number_3 >= Number_5) and (Number_3 >= Number_6):
                largest_Number = Number_3
            else:
                if (Number_4 >= Number_1) and (Number_4 >= Number_2) and (Number_4 >= Number_3) and (Number_4 >= Number_5) and (Number_4 >= Number_6):
                    largest_Number = Number_4
                else:
                    if (Number_5 >= Number_1) and (Number_5 >= Number_2) and (Number_5 >= Number_3) and (Number_5 >= Number_4) and (Number_5 >= Number_6):
                        largest_Number = Number_5
                    else:
                        if (Number_6 >= Number_1) and (Number_6 >= Number_2) and (Number_6 >= Number_3) and (Number_6 >= Number_4) and (Number_6 >= Number_5):
                            largest_Number = Number_6
    print(largest_Number)
```

Few hints, you can use `if...elif..else` in your code

```
def largest(Number_1, Number_2, Number_3, Number_4, Number_5, Number_6):
    if (Number_1 >= Number_2) and (Number_1 >= Number_3) and (Number_1 >= Number_4) and (Number_1 >= Number_5) and (Number_1 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_1;
    elif (Number_2 >= Number_1) and (Number_2 >= Number_3) and (Number_2 >= Number_4) and (Number_2 >= Number_5) and (Number_2 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_2
    elif (Number_3 >= Number_1) and (Number_3 >= Number_2) and (Number_3 >= Number_4) and (Number_3 >= Number_5) and (Number_3 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_3
    elif (Number_4 >= Number_1) and (Number_4 >= Number_2) and (Number_4 >= Number_3) and (Number_4 >= Number_5) and (Number_4 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_4
    elif (Number_5 >= Number_1) and (Number_5 >= Number_2) and (Number_5 >= Number_3) and (Number_5 >= Number_4) and (Number_5 >= Number_6):
        largest_Number = Number_5
    elif (Number_6 >= Number_1) and (Number_6 >= Number_2) and (Number_6 >= Number_3) and (Number_6 >= Number_4) and (Number_6 >= Number_5):
        largest_Number = Number_6
    print(largest_Number)
```

A minor issue was your `print(largest_Number)` should be outside the `if` conditions.